# Making a Leaflet line feature more 'grabbable'

Tags: leaflet, line

Is there a way to increase the buffer that makes a line clickable in Leaflet?

I know you can increase the width of the line, but the symbology of my feature should not be altered in this case; it should remain exactly as shown in the screenshots below.

For instance, here the line is clickable:

[image]

But here it is not, even though the cursor is only a few pixels off:

[image]

In OpenLayers I can achieve this pretty easily with the available styling options, which you can tweak to add an *invisible buffer*, but in Leaflet this does not seem to be possible.

Are there any simple ways to achieve this effect?

I am usinga *GeoJSON*, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the plugin Leaflet Almost Over

http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.AlmostOver/

https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.AlmostOver